# Exist a Helicopter model?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I was wondering if exit a helicopter 3D model in Gasebo.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17316/exist-a-helicopter-model-?/) by [Jezel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3871/jezel/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can try this:

http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2017-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jezel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3871/jezel/) on 2017-09-26**:
Thanks a lot